# Moving local wordpress to new folder - Fix broken links

Tags: localhost

I have a WordPress site on localhost (Mamp), and i made another site so instead of having the first site as the direct localhost for mamp i made a folder with several sites so i can just go to localhost and then pick which one i would like to work on.

As i did is, the first site didnt work anymore and i figured its probly because the links arent the same anymore since now its localhost/site instead of localhost, so i went in the database and runned this query to change the links on all elements (homepage, pages, posts, pictures and so on)

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'localhost', 'localhost/site/');
```

I took this query from wpbeginner.com and it should work but it only works on the homepage. Everything else as pages, posts and pictures doesnt work, it just says "Not Found

The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server."

When i create new pages on the site i get the same error.

What is a good way to solve this?

I could just reinstall everything but i know its not necessary if you do it the correct way, which i obviously havent after what happened.

Answer (score 0):

I managed fixing it now, i tried changing the localhost name in the wp-config file but got an error because its not the same in the database, then i just checked the permalinks in wordpress and it looked fine, but i tried a different type and then it worked for some reason. Then i changed the permalinks back to the normal type and it still worked.

If anyone would like to explain why did happen id be glad.